# Как сделать выплывающую подсказку для картинки?

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, в интернете ничего найти не могу.
Нужно сделать появление всплывающей подсказки когда пользователь наводит курсор на картинку

```html
<img class="insta" src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/instagram-app-icon-social-media-logo-vector-illustration_277909-403.jpg" alt="" height="80px" width="80px">
```

Comment: tooltip ? :hover ? по-моему так, я правильно поняла, нужно показать подсказку при наведении => у image есть св-во `alt`/title

Comment: Просто в `alt="Что-то тут напишите"`

Comment: через alt не работает

Comment: Alt в html — это атрибут тега img, который нужен для установки подписи (альтернативного названия) изображения на сайте. Если картинка по каким-либо причинам оказывается отключенной, текст дает понять, что там изображено

Comment: а мне нужно что бы при наведении на картинку курсором она вылезла

Comment: вылезала сбоку или на самой картинке ?

Answer (score 3):

```html
<img class="insta" src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/instagram-app-icon-social-media-logo-vector-illustration_277909-403.jpg" alt="а это для плоховидящих" height="80px" width="80px" title="вот ваша подсказка">
```

используйте `title`, чтоб показать подсказку

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qykrj.png пару секунд подержите мышку

Comment: поняла, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Смотря какого формата подсказка нужна. Если просто обычный текст - то да, `title` будет вполне достаточно.
Если нужен какой-то кастомный всплывающий балун, то рекомендую попробовать **[tippyjs](https://tippyjs.bootcss.com/)** (https://tippyjs.bootcss.com/)

Простенький пример. В документации есть больше вариантов кастомизации.

```js
tippy('#myButton', {
  content: "Просто нажми на меня"
});
tippy('#myImage', {
  content: "Просто кот"
});
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Просто кнопка</button>
<br /><br />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" id="myImage" title="Тайтл у картинки"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5/dist/backdrop.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5/dist/tippy-bundle.iife.js"></script>
```